# Exact nature of HOMO of square planar isomer of tetraamminemagnesium(0)

Tags: computational-chemistry

I need to calculate information about the (hypothetical) square-planar form of the tetraamminemagnesium(0) molecule as a reference to my personal QC research project; everything goes fine until we go to the HOMO and LUMO.

If I use Hartree-Fock with basis set 6-311G(2d, p) on Gaussian, I get an antibonding s-type orbital moderately localised on the magnesium as the HOMO. Same goes when I use MP2 with the same basis set. However, if I calculate the same calculation while using the keyword Guess=Huckel, I get a nonbonding p-type orbital highly localised on the magnesium as the HOMO. Moreover, in both cases, the HOMO is mostly consisted of the core and/or Rydberg orbitals of the magnesium and nitrogens; these two (or three) inconsistencies happen irrespectively of the basis set used, from STO-3G to cc-pVDZ.

While calculating, I noticed that the HOMO-LUMO gap is quite small(about 0.1 Ha, approx. 2~3eV), which means that any small error can lead to a "switching" of the HOMO and the LUMO.

My question now follows; which is the exact symmetry and (anti)bondingness of the square planar, Ci-symmetric isomer of tetraamminemagnesium(0)? The magnesium-nitrogen bonds are all 1.9 angstroms, the nitrogen-hydrogen bonds all 1 angstrom, and the three propeller hydrogens of each ammine ligand have dihedral angles of 30°, 90° and 150° (resp.) with respect to the plane consisting of the magnesium and the four nitrogens.

Comment: Are you talking about the Hartree-Fock orbitals or the orbitals coming from NBO calculation? Small HOMO-LUMO gap is usually indicative of static correlation i.e. you would need a multiconfigurational calculation to actually model the system.

Comment: Hartree-Fock only.

Comment: I think you could try DFT and see what you get. Sometimes they perform better for systems with static correlation. (MP2 is very bad with those systems)

Comment: It says, "an ambiguous keyword was detected" when I tried to use the keyword DFT.

Comment: Just tried BLYP- looks like the HOMO is indeed of antibonding s-character.

Comment: Yeah you can't use DFT, you have to specify a functional. Why don't you try TPSS instead of BLYP? It's better for static correlation(https://aip.scitation.org/doi/am-pdf/10.1063/1.4991833). Also, if you don't know what DFT is, maybe you should brush up on the core areas before delving into such complicated calculations? I would not do multireference systems before getting the hang of single reference closed shell molecules.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127943/discussion-between-just-some-nerdy-teen-and-s-r-maiti).